# Azure AD - Add app principal to a Group

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adal

I have an Azure AD app (AAD App1) which has user assignment enabled. So only, users from a particular group let's say "Group A" can access any resource (let's say an Azure Function API) protected by that Azure AD app.
[image]
[image]
Now I have another daemon Azure function job, which needs to make an authenticated call to the above mentioned Azure function API. Since this is a daemon job, I have generated another Azure AD app (AAD App2) for this. 
Below is my code to get access tokens:

```
 string resourceId = "id of app used to authenticate azure function";  // AAD app ID used by the Azure function for authentication
            string clientId = "id of app registered for the daemon job";// AAD app ID of your console app
            string clientSecret = "secret of app registered for the daemon job"; // Client secret of the AAD app registered for console app
            string resourceUrl = "https://blahblah.azurewebsites.net/api/events"; 
            string domain = "<mytenant>.onmicrosoft.com";   //Tenant domain
            var accessToken = await TokenHelper.GetAppOnlyAccessToken(domain, resourceId, clientId, clientSecret);
```

Now when I try to generate access token to access the Azure function API, I get an invalid grant error as below:

> AdalException:
>   {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS50105: Application
>   '' is not assigned to a role for the application
>   ''.\r\nTrace ID:
>   6df90cf440-c16d-480e-8daf-2349ddef3800\r\nCorrelation ID:
>   4c4bf7bf-2140-4e01-93e3-b85d1ddfc09d4d\r\nTimestamp: 2018-05-09
>   17:28:11Z","error_codes":[50105],"timestamp":"2018-05-09
>   17:28:11Z","trace_id":"690cf440-c16d-480e-8daf-2349ddef3800","correlation_id":"4c4bf7bf-2140-4e01-93ef3-b85d1dc09d4d"}:
>   Unknown error

I am able to properly generate AAD access tokens if I disable the user assignment.

I am trying to avoid creating a service account here. Is there anyway I can add an app principal to an Azure AD group or add it as a member of another Azure AD app?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you cannot add an AAD application/service principal as a member of Azure AD group.

I have confirmed this issue in [My Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47762262/add-aad-application-as-a-member-of-a-security-group/47769755#47769755) for another similar question [**EDIT - now seems to be possible, see said answer**]

You can also upvote [**this idea in our Feedback Forum**](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/33784624-allow-applications-to-be-added-to-ad-security-grou). Azure AD Team will review it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for confirming.

Comment: @Unnie . My pleasure.  I will also report this case to Azure Team.If this have any response, I will keep you updated.

Comment: Strangely we have found a work around to make it work. Will post it here, it might interest you

Comment: If I generate access token with resource and clientid same as the daemon app with no user assignment. Then add the client id of the consuming app in the "Allowed token audience" of Azure functions, then my user assignment set up in the Azure AD app is ignored and I get data back from the Azure function

Comment: Hi,@Unnie. I'm not sure if this work around is a general solution. But if it works for you, it should be great!

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT there was an update in the feedfack forum you linked in your answer: it seems that now is possible to ad SP to groups. It says: "This is possible today using PowerShell, however that is not an ideal experience. So we are also investigating improving the Azure portal experience to support searching for apps in the group membership picker. Stay tuned"