# Grouping applications on the azure portal

Tags: azure, active-directory

I want to group applications available on the Azure marketplace and then assign those groups to the users or user group.

Is it possible with AAD?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is not possible to directly group the application on the azure application portal. We have created a separate application that is accessing these application's data through the Azure APIs and grouping the applications at our end.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible with AAD?

You cannot. You could assign the user or group to the application, but cannot create a group for the applications. To assign the user or group to the application, you could read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/methods-for-assigning-users-and-groups).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there any supporting document stating that we cannot group the applications.

Comment: @ManishKumar, for this, you could refer to the [lilnk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47762262/add-aad-application-as-a-member-of-a-security-group/47769755) here. Hope it could help you.