# How do I query service principal group membership with the Microsoft.Graph library?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

Recently, AAD added the ability to put service principals in security groups ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47769755/2852699)). Given a service principal object ID, how do I query its security group memberships with the [Microsoft.Graph library](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet)? I tried the following:

```
var groups = client.Users[servicePrincipalId].GetMemberGroups(true).Request().PostAsync().Result;
```

but then get the error:

> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: Request_ResourceNotFound
>   Message: Resource '$servicePrincipalId' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.

I tried using DirectoryObject instead:

```
var groups = client.DirectoryObjects[servicePrincipalId].GetMemberGroups(true).Request().PostAsync().Result;
```

but then get the error:

> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: CodeMessage: Unsupported directory object class 'ServicePrincipal' specified by resource identifier.

How do I get info about service principals? Is it not supported yet and I have to use the REST API or something? I'm using the 1.17.0 Microsoft.Graph NuGet package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At present time you have to use the [Microsoft.Graph.Beta library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph.Beta/0.8.0-preview), which adds support for service principals:

```
var groups = client.ServicePrincipals[servicePrincipalId].GetMemberGroups(true).Request().PostAsync().Result;
```

You can alternatively use the `CheckMemberGroups(new string[] { groupId })` method.